# How to connect multiple machines to a private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I have created a private blockchain in my machine using geth and now i need multiple machines to connect to that same blockchain and use the contracts deployed in that private blockchain from all machines connected to that blockchain. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect multiple machines to a private blockchain :

Then anther machines add this network then addPeer : Example :

```
admin.addPeer("enode://a902f3231e561546896f4619bb7129e67f3b46ee4bc6a86e35ca1f575444e9f25dcb65bf0e09b02fd2714ce59bbb496a7783486d39eca4a17327ae1bacb3c699@10.42.0.40:30303")
```

IP configuration (enode creation with ip address)

10.42.0.40 this miens anther computer ip: example 192.168.0.101

Example :

```
admin.addPeer("enode://a902f3231e561546896f4619bb7129e67f3b46ee4bc6a86e35ca1f575444e9f25dcb65bf0e09b02fd2714ce59bbb496a7783486d39eca4a17327ae1bacb3c699@192.168.0.101:30303")
```

Then peer check this commend run :

```
-> admin
```

and anther machines multiple nodes add.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome @ Monica Mohandas

Answer (score 0):

Important is that they use the same genesis block.

Try the following command while running the nodes in the console:

> admin.nodeInfo

Do it with every Node and if they have different genesis block or different network id, something is wrong with the genesis.json file, because both have to be similiar.